# Limit Definition of Functional Derivative for multifunction functionals

Tags: calculus-of-variations

Imagine variational calculus on nonlinear multifunction functionals. Let 
$C^k[a,b]$ denote the set of all $k$ times differentiable functions from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Now consider a functional $F[\mu,\lambda]:C^k[a,b] \times C^k[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$, and the extrema of this functional.

So, for example, one class of functional that arose of interest to me in this area was $$\mathbb{D}[x,y] = \int_0^1 \sqrt{\left(\frac{\text{d}x(\ell)}{\text{d} \ell} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{\text{d}y(\ell)}{\text{d}\ell} \right)^2} \ \text{d}\ell + k_{\omega} \left(1 - \exp{\left(\int_0^1 \ln{\left( \iint_{\Omega} \psi\left(\left \langle \begin{matrix} x(\ell) \\ y(\ell) \end{matrix} \right \rangle,\left \langle \begin{matrix} x_\pi \\ y_\pi \end{matrix} \right \rangle  \right) \sigma\left(\left \langle \begin{matrix} x_\pi \\ y_\pi \end{matrix} \right \rangle \right) \ \text{d}x_\pi \ \text{d}y_\pi \right)}  \ \text{d}\ell \right) } \right) $$ 
where $x(\ell)$ and $y(\ell)$ are any real valued functions from the unit interval to the numberline, and $\psi$ and $\sigma$ are positive real-valued functions. This is example isn't strictly relevant to the question but it may offer some insight into what I'm asking about.

In the most general form, for a functional $F$ like that written above, I think any extremizing pair of functions $\mu$ and $\lambda$ must be unimprovable by small variations in both directions, requiring that for any pair of functions $\xi$ and $\eta$ vanishing on the boundary, so I'm pretty sure that it's necessary for any extremizers to satisfy

$$\forall \xi, \eta: \lim_{(\varepsilon_\mu, \varepsilon_\lambda) \to(0,0)} \frac{F[\mu + \varepsilon_\mu \xi, \lambda + \varepsilon_\lambda \eta]-F[\mu, \lambda]}{\sqrt{\varepsilon_\mu^2 + \varepsilon_\lambda^2}} = 0 $$

(I should note that I'm not sure this is the best limit definition. The denominator may be in fact something like $\varepsilon_\mu \varepsilon_\lambda$). Now, within non linearity of the functional I think it's possible this is not equivalent to the simultaneous conditions $$\forall \xi: \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \frac{F[\mu + \varepsilon \xi, \lambda]-F[\mu, \lambda]}{\varepsilon} $$ and $$\forall \eta: \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \frac{F[\mu , \lambda+\varepsilon \eta]-F[\mu, \lambda]}{\varepsilon} $$ but I think it's possible that I can, for most functionals at least, rewrite this as

$$\forall \xi, \eta: \lim_{\varepsilon\to0} \frac{F[\mu + \varepsilon \xi, \lambda + \varepsilon \eta]-F[\mu, \lambda]}{\varepsilon\sqrt2} = 0 $$

of course meaning that the limit does in fact exist and is the same for all paths.
So, my question is this:

**1. What is the best limit definition of the functional derivative for multifunction functionals?**

and

**2. For what classes of functions can we simplify this limit definition, especially by rewriting it as a pair of simultaneous conditions each varying one of the functions?**